# palindrome function does not return value

Tags: python

I have made the following code to test if a word in a list is a palindrome or not:

```
def test(wordlist,ini,end,f):
    if ini>end/2 or f==False:
        return f
    else:
        if wordlist[ini]==wordlist[end]:
            f=True
        else:
            f=False
        ini=ini+1
        end=end-1
        test(wordlist,ini,end,f)
```

I have put some print messages inside the code and I check that it works, but the problem that I have is that it does not return a value of true or false; I am testing with something like this:

test(['a','b','b','a'],0,3)

what am I missing?

Comment: You have two cases, and only `return` in one of them...

Comment: ... and the true palindrome function is `wordlist == wordlist[::-1]` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line of your function:

```
    test(wordlist,ini,end,f)
```

You have to explicitly `return` this.

```
    return test(wordlist,ini,end,f)
```